# JPA inheritance mapping with discriminator on existing column

Tags: spring, inheritance, jpa, eclipselink, spring-social

I'm using JPA and EclipseLink with Spring and SpringSecurity frameworks.

I've got a JOINED inheritance mapping between a `User` table and a `Seller` table that extends it.
Each user has got a `ROLE_FK` column (which is needed for authentication) which refers to a `ROLES` table.

I'd like to use this `ROLE_FK` column as **Discriminator** column. Is there a way to do so, or I'm forced to use a specific **DiscriminatorColumn** in addition to `ROLE_FK`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a DiscriminatorColumn, but potentially you could make the ROLE_FK be the DiscriminatorColumn.

A separate discriminator will probably be easier and more straight forward though.

EclipseLink also allows you to use a @ClassExtracor to determine the class,

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/Inheritance#.40ClassExtractor